# Find distance between two person with depth map

Tags: computer-vision

Assume I could have a depth map of this image.

[image]

I could measure the distance of the man with red rectangle between the camera, and the women with red rectangle between the camera with the help of depth map, but how could I measure the distance between both of them(the man and women draw by the red rectangle). Is this possible to done with depth map?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the camera stationary?
This approach would be really simple, but could produce decent results:

Assuming the camera is stationary: if you know the length of one of the tiles on the floor (e.g. the one where the gate ends) or the distance between the poles in the gate, you can get a rough estimate on how much distance one pixel covers. You could then estimate the distance between the two people based on how many pixels are between them. (This would of course neglect depth information)

Comment: Yes, stationary. Find a reference object is the easiest solution I could come up, ultimate propose is do not rely on reference any object. If depth map could achieve this results would be awesome